# Chaoticity and randomness in a time series

Tags: random, chaos-theory

Suppose we have a time series : $X=\{X_t,t\in T\}$. How can we check if the data $X_t$ are random or they are the result of some chaotic behaviour of a nonlinear dynamical system? Is there some test useful to prove the chaoticity of the series? Thanks.

Comment: You can't, not without some restrictive assumptions about the structure and complexity of the dynamical system. Consider that a cryptographic PRNG (as implemented in hardware if you like) _is_ a nonlinear dynamical system; if you could recognize those in general, you'd have a _universal distinguishing attack_ and turn cryptography on its head. There are well-known [randomness tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests) available, but their accuracy is limited, and for a sufficiently complex system they may declare the output to look random even if it isn't.

Comment: you might look up the work of some subset of brock, lebaron and scheinkman, e.g. http://www.amazon.com/Nonlinear-Dynamics-Chaos-Instability-Statistical/dp/B005OL99XO which is at least good for a laugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply chaotic time series analysis to the data. There are some useful tools about this subject [here](http://www.mpipks-dresden.mpg.de/~tisean/). Such implementations try to find positive Lyapunov exponents from the data set based on the studies of Rosenstein et. al. ("A practical method for calculating largest Lyapunov exponents from small data sets") or Wolf et. al. ("Determining Lyapunov exponents from a time series"). You can also check the [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198508409) of the Julien Sprott about this subject.

If you can find positive Lyapunov exponents with the above methods you can say that the time series is chaotic. However, as Henning Makholm stated, randomness is a different case. You can apply statistical randomness tests to a sufficiently big data just to conclude that the hypothesis about randomness cannot be rejected for a [significance level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance).